# Isn't validation process working on the server-side in Struts 2?

Tags: validation, struts2, server-side, concept

I get confused with the concept of validation in Struts. `ActionSupport` class provides the `validation()` method

```java
public void validate(){}
```

which is used to validate the form. But isn't this process working on the server- side?

If it is then, is it fails the concept of validation?

Comment: *fails the concept of validation*? Care to elaborate?

Comment: I think you need to first learn about client-side and server-side validations.

Comment: You should be more specific about what are you asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't clear.

Yes, an action's `validate()` method obviously validates on the server side.

This is a Good Thing, because data *must* be validated on the server side, regardless of whether or not any client-side validation occurs. Consider (a) users that have JavaScript disabled, and (b) hand-crafted requests not made through a browser. While (a) is increasingly 
uncommon, (b) is a legitimate danger.

You cannot rely on JS-only validation.

Comment: This method works only in the *programmatic* validation is on (Defaults to true).

Comment: It means we have to validate the form in both client and server side

Comment: @Subodh No, it doesn't, although in general it's a better UX if you do. But you *cannot* skip server-side validation.

Comment: @RomanC An Ajax request is a request like any other; they still need to be validated, IMO. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually I disagree with YO but it doesn't matter, because I didn't like it.

Comment: @RomanC What justification is there for not validating the data of a web request? Data is data; it doesn't matter how it's coming in to the system. If you have a field like, say, a social security number that should adhere to a specific format or pattern, whether it comes in as a posted form field or in an Ajax request it still needs to adhere to that format or pattern. Once it hits your server you can't just say "Oh it must be okay because it came from an Ajax request", because anybody can send an Ajax request if they're using your app.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't this process work on server-side?

Of course, it is a [validation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html) on the server-side. By default Struts 2 is configured to use *programmatic* validation regardless of *declarative* way.

Both are server-side, Struts2 also has a client-side validation that is using JavaScript. **The rightful thing if you use validation both on
the client-side and on the server-side**.

If your action class extends `ActionSupport`, you can override the `validate()` method to use with programmatic validation method used by the framework. In the method body you can implement your custom logic to validate fields.

The `validate()` method is called by the [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) which is a part of the default interceptor stack `defaultStack`.

The action should provide the `INPUT` result to return action errors or field errors.

More about programmatic validation using [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) you can find in this link.