# Validate method called after the execute method of struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I am using struts 2 and hibernate framework and had developed a small CRUD to enter data into mysql db, and validating the fields

### Student.java

```
    package com.struts2hibernatepagination.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    private int marks;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

}
```

### AddStudentAction.java

```
package com.struts2hibernatepagination.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.struts2hibernatepagination.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.struts2hibernatepagination.hibernate.Student;

public class AddStudentAction extends ActionSupport implements
        ModelDriven<Student> {

    public AddStudentAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private Student student = new Student();

    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    StudentDAO dao = new StudentDAO();

    @Override
    public Student getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return student;
    }
@Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dao.addStudent(student);
        String f = student.getFirstName();
        String l = student.getLastName();
        int m = student.getMarks();
        System.out.println(f + l + m + "Inside execute method");
        return "success";
    }

    public String listStudents() {
        students = dao.getStudents();
        return "success";
    }
@Override
    public void validate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (student.getFirstName() == null) {

            String first = student.getFirstName();

            System.out.println(first);//this statement is returning null
            this.addActionError("Please Enter First Name !!!");
            System.out.println("Inside validate method!!");
        }
        // super.validate();
    }
}
```

### student.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<s:head />
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="addStudent">
        <s:actionerror />
        <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name" />
        <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name" />
        <s:textfield name="marks" label="Marks" />
        <s:submit />
        <hr />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
            </tr>
            <s:iterator value="students">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="firstName" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="lastName" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="marks" /></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>

    </s:form>
    <s:form action="fetchStudentList">
        <s:submit>See All Student List</s:submit>

    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

### StudentDAO.java

```
package com.struts2hibernatepagination.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;
import com.struts2hibernatepagination.hibernate.Student;

public class StudentDAO {

    // The session object and transaction object will be injected using the
    // @SessionTarget
    // and @TransactionTarget annotation respectively.

    @SessionTarget
    Session session;

    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction transaction;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {
            students = session.createQuery("from Student").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return students;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        try {
            session.save(student);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">

        <action name="addStudent" method="execute"
            class="com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction">



            <result name="success" type="redirect">
                listStudents
            </result>

            <result name="input">/student.jsp</result>




        </action>

        <action name="listStudents" method="listStudents"
            class="com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction">
        <result name="success">/student.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/student.jsp</result>




    </action>

    <action name="fetchStudentList"
        class="com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction"
        method="listStudents">

        <result name="success">/displaytag.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/student.jsp</result>


    </action>

</package>
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin12345</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3306/nupur</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.struts2hibernatepagination.hibernate.Student" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In the above code, the execute method is called first after the submit button is pressed on student.jsp and after that validate is been called, hence even when I enter firstname it raises error to enter firstname, since the validation is done after the data is inserted in db, where I am getting wrong? I need to call validate method first.

### Console :

```
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Preparing Injection Hibernate Session and Transaction process: /addStudent - Method: com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction.execute() 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory: destroy factory required... 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory: C3P0 not found 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory: All SessionFactories Destroyed sucessful 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: No Hibernate Session in current thread. New Hibernate Session will be created and returned (SessionFactory "(default)") 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: New Hibernate Session required - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory build started... 
17:36:12 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory using Hibernate Annotation Configuration 
17:36:13 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory configuration file "/hibernate.cfg.xml" configured 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: SessionFactory "" configured from "/hibernate.cfg.xml" file 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: "" configured as the *default* SessionFactory of the Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory  
17:36:14 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin's Session Factory built successful 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: New Hibernate Session created and returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "com.struts2hibernatepagination.dao.StudentDAO" 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin Validation in class com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction 
17:36:14 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin Validation found no erros. 
Hibernate: insert into student (last_name, first_name, marks) values (?, ?, ?)
**TinaDutta44Inside execute method**
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transation  org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction@1d4fbd1 rolledback by Full Hibernate Plugin 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session closed 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session closed by Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction Committed 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Injection Hibernate Session and Transaction process for /addStudent - Method: com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction.execute() finished 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Preparing Injection Hibernate Session and Transaction process: /listStudents - Method: com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction.listStudents() 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: No Hibernate Session in current thread. New Hibernate Session will be created and returned (SessionFactory "(default)") 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: New Hibernate Session required - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: New Hibernate Session created and returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "com.struts2hibernatepagination.dao.StudentDAO" 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin Validation in class com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction 
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin Validation found no erros. 
**null
Inside validate method!!**
17:36:15 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin found custom validation errors: {} [Please Enter First Name !!!] 
17:36:16 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transation  org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction@6ee964 rolledback by Full Hibernate Plugin 
17:36:16 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session closed 
17:36:16 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session closed by Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:36:16 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction Committed 
17:36:16 - DEBUG: Injection Hibernate Session and Transaction process for /listStudents - Method: com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction.listStudents() finished
```

Comment: What is the error? Post your error logs

Comment: Actually, there is no error , but even when I enter the first name then also the exception is been raised, moreover I debugged the program and printed some sout statements in that execute method sout is printed first and then validate method sout is printed, and also the bean class object is returning null when I try to acces it in validate method.

Comment: @Override
    public void validate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (student.getFirstName() == null) {

            String first = student.getFirstName();

            System.out.println(first);
            this.addActionError("Please Enter First Name !!!");
            System.out.println("Inside validate method!!");
        }
        // super.validate();
    }                                                                                                                           System.out.println(first); // this line in validate method is returning null

Comment: don't add code in the comments. Instead edit your post to add the additional content

Comment: How do you know that a validate method is called after execute?

Comment: Because in the console the sout of execute method is pritned first and insert query is generated and data is inserted and after that control comes in validate method

Comment: I have asked how "control comes in validate method"? Did you sysout it or brakepoint in the debug?

Comment: Console http://pastebin.com/zFVAYqPZ

Comment: I used sout statements for it

Comment: Post stacktrace when validation is called.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nkKN4jXj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in the debugs that the plugin performs it's own validation. It's not Struts validation, but a bean validation with Hibernate Validator.

You should choose the validation framework that better suits your needs. If you enable Struts validation with `defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation` then you should exclude some action methods from validation and remove `input` result.

```xml
<action name="listStudents" method="listStudents"
        class="com.struts2hibernatepagination.action.AddStudentAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation">
       <param name="validation.excludeMethods">listStudents</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">/student.jsp</result>
</action>
```

---

The other actions also need that stack `defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation`, so you better use in the package

```xml
<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation"/>
```

Comment: Hi sir, I added this action tag in my struts.xml but the data is inserted when I fill all the fields, now my problem is that, validation is not been done even though I did not enter the firstName field then also the data is inserting in the database

Comment: Should I add the interceptor-ref tag in addstudent action tag instead of liststudent?

Comment: I have added it for all actions in the package

Comment: I used it in the package , but then also the data is inserting in db without validating

Comment: I don't see values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k9Gxme6Z the values are not showing in insert query bu the data is been inserted in db

Comment: The problem is not of insertion but of validation, data is inserting but validation is no been done!!

Comment: The validation is performed by the validation interceptor. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22378838/573032

Comment: defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation interceptor contains validation then why the validate method is not called?? Where I am getting wrong,none of the sout statements are printed of validate method neither the validation is done

Comment: It should be called but you might not see it. Put sysout statement first of the `validate()`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sFE0g8x3, validate method inside code is not executed only the entry and exit sysout statements is been printed.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m0twDciM   Finally found my mistake, after printing a lot of sout statements, I found out that the lenght of the string if I am not entering is 0 not null, whereas in validate method I have put only one condition to do validation i.e if the string is null then only it will do validation , but in my case string was of 0 length not null, hence the validation was not occurring, thanks a ton Roman C sir, you helped me alot, I was stuck with this from 2-3 days... Thanks !!!! :)